# What is the name for a chord with two suspensions?

Tags: chord-theory

Specifically, the chord I'm wondering about is one with Root, 2nd, 4th, minor 7th.

**Example**

So let's say it's `D, E, G, C`.

My thinking is to call it `Dm7sus2sus4`, but that becomes quite the mouthful.

Additionally, I don't know if it can be called a sus2, since the root is already there. My understanding is that a sus2 would resolve to the root.

`Dm7sus4add9`?

**Side note**

It's only from context that I've decided on the D approach. The set of notes can, as far as my understanding reaches, also be a `Cadd9/D`, possibly `Em7add6/D` or `G6add13(no 3)/D`.

But barring these alternatives, does it have a name that *begins* with D?

Comment: Sus chords change the 3rd for either a 2nd or a 4th. Either of these usually moves back - as in a sus chord is usually followed by the same root chord, in simple triad form. So the sus part 'resolves' to the chord's 3rd. your CEGD could easily be Cadd9/D, but it may depend on what its function is in what key.

Comment: @Tim - Yes, but in this case, the third is changed for both. Do we then call it "sus2sus4"?

Comment: It's just a C9 (or Cadd2) without the C underneath. With no other context I can't hear it any other way.

Comment: Yeah, I proposed Cadd9/D as well as a few other /D chords in the question, but I should have been more specific: Is there a way to name this that *starts* with D?

Comment: It can't be Dm7 at all: there's no F to make minor, but the 7th would be C anyway.

Comment: @Alec why do you want it to start with D?

Comment: @Peter - As practice, I'm trying to name the chord once for each note as root. That's why I listed Cadd9/D, and the E and G alternatives. But I'm stuck on what one does with this configuration for D.

Comment: @Alec I see, then your G alternative is incorrect because 6 and 13 are the same note. G6sus4/D would be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Peter - You're right. Somehow got duplicated there. Also, I don't know when to call it a 6th and when to call it a 13th. But that would be a separate question, unless it's already been answered around here somewhere.

Comment: Rooting it on D, your options are D9(sus4omit5), D7(sus2,4omit5), D7(sus2add11omit5), or D11(omit3,5). Without introducing slash chords, an extensive list is presented here: http://www.tomweissmusic.com/chords/?pitchclass=0247    I’ve asked about 6 vs 13th chords here before:  https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/when-a-major-6th-or-an-octave-thereof-is-in-a-chord-when-is-the-interval-iden

Comment: That's a C+9. Falling over yourself to name it a D chord isn't an exercise which will make your music any easier to read or understand.

Comment: @AJFaraday - As I mentioned, the only reason I'm falling over myself to do so, is as an exercise, and not for readability. C/D or Cadd9/D are absolutely my go-to for this chord.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C/D is the simplest version. Perhaps D9sus4 if you want D to be the first letter.

Comment: Wouldn't D9 imply that we're stacking thirds? We have the fifth and seventh, but no third, so I skipped the idea of D9sus4 for that reason.

Comment: @Alec When a performer sees "sus4" after a chord, it tells them to raise the 3rd to a 4th (so F# becomes G in this case). So, D9sus4 would include these notes: D, G, A, C, E. There is no 5th in the chord you wrote in your post, so if you really don't want them to the A, you could write D9sus4 (omit 5).

Comment: Oh, my brain isn't performing today. Of course the suspension replaces the 3rd. Yeah, I definitely like D9sus4(no 5) then.

Comment: It's funny. C/D exactly fits the list of tones `D E G C` but then it seems to mean `Cadd9` inverted... so suspensions. I suppose if `Dm7sus2sus4` was intended the tone list should be `E G A C` then if truly a suspension it would resolve to `D F A C`. So the question may be mixed up about what chord is intended. +1 for a chord symbol that does match _exactly_ the list of tones in the question.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Yeah, it's a classic theory vs. practice problem. If you're trying to describe the theoretical function of the suspensions, then C/D doesn't do that, but it is the most practical way to convey this set of notes to a performer.

Answer (score 2):

In classical music, this would be labeled probably a 9-8 4-3 suspension (close enough). Also I believe "double suspension" is sufficient most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe* you could use `Dm11`.

That gives `E` the 9th, `G` the 11th, and `C` the 7th.

But, the `F` and `A` being omitted isn't captured by that particular symbol. If those omissions are *important* a `m11` is not a good choice.

If you *must* be clear the chord is a suspension, you seem stuck with the `sus` and also should not use `add`.

Comment: How do you reach a minor chord there? Assuming D is the root, there's no minor third.

Comment: @AJFaraday, I used a minor, because the OP suggested `Dm`. But if you re-read my short answer... "But, the F and A being omitted isn't captured by that particular symbol. If those omissions are important a m11 is not a good choice." Why are you asking me a question, that I already addressed in my answer?